# create-nx-workspace latest version (16.1.1) create npm conflict

Tags: nrwl-nx

I use the latest create-nx-workspace (16.1.1)

$ npx create-nx-workspace xxx --preset angular-monorepo

git push

then
do `npm install` again, got lots of warning, seems 16.1.1 is buggy? How do I resolve this?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: jest-preset-angular@13.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">= 14.0.0 < 17.0.0" from @nx/angular@16.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nx/angular
npm ERR!     @nx/angular@"16.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     @nx/angular@"16.1.1" from @nrwl/angular@16.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@nrwl/angular
npm ERR!       @nrwl/angular@"16.1.1" from @nx/angular@16.1.1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=13.0.0 <16.0.0" from jest-preset-angular@13.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/jest-preset-angular
npm ERR!   dev jest-preset-angular@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=13.0.0 <16.0.0" from jest-preset-angular@13.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/jest-preset-angular
npm ERR!     dev jest-preset-angular@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: We're waiting for [a new release](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/commit/18abd21fc63f4c3669878ed74f5a380852c4c193) of jest-preset-angular

Comment: Hi, jest-preset-angular 13.1.0 has just been released. You can give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and the solution for me was upgrading `angular-preset-jest` to `13.1.0` or later.

Try installing the latest version:

```bash
npm i -D jest-preset-angular@latest
```